# SonarQube docker image does not run successfully under App Service ACI

Tags: sql-server, docker, azure-devops, sonarqube, connection-timeout

I try to implement sonarqube continuous inspection in azure devops with help of windows container instance. After creating azure sonarqube instance (Docker sonarqube latest image) and azure sql database, I try to bind sonarqube windows instance with azure sql server with help of below azure CLI command :

```
az webapp config connection-string set --resource-group $RESOURCE_GROUP_NAME --name $WEBAPP_NAME -t SQLAzure --settings SONARQUBE_JDBC_URL=$DB_CONNECTION_STRING --connection-string-type SQLAzure

az webapp config container set --name $WEBAPP_NAME--resource-group $RESOURCE_GROUP_NAME --docker-custom-image-name $CONTAINER_REGISTRY_FQDN/$CONTAINER_IMAGE_NAME:$CONTAINER_IMAGE_TAG --docker-registry-server-url https://$CONTAINER_REGISTRY_FQDN --docker-registry-server-user $REG_ADMIN_USER --docker-registry-server-password $REG_ADMIN_PASSWORD
```

for this i used server less sonarqube setup approach derived in below article:
https://github.com/Hupka/sonarqube-azure-setup

But i am getting below container logs while running sonarqube container instance:

```
2019-06-13 14:28:34.362 INFO  - Logging is not enabled for this container.
Please use https://aka.ms/linux-diagnostics to enable logging to see container logs here.
2019-06-13 14:28:38.819 INFO  - Initiating warmup request to container SonarQubewebappName for site sonarqube-docker
2019-06-13 14:28:54.260 INFO  - Waiting for response to warmup request for container SonarQubewebappName. Elapsed time = 15.4410269 sec
2019-06-13 14:29:12.285 INFO  - Waiting for response to warmup request for container SonarQubewebappName. Elapsed time = 33.4654201 sec
2019-06-13 14:29:28.296 INFO  - Waiting for response to warmup request for container SonarQubewebappName. Elapsed time = 49.4772459 sec
2019-06-13 14:29:44.637 INFO  - Waiting for response to warmup request for container SonarQubewebappName. Elapsed time = 65.8173845 sec
**2019-06-13 14:29:56.670 ERROR - Container SonarQubewebappName for site SonarQubewebappName has exited, failing site start
2019-06-13 14:29:56.693 ERROR - Container SonarQubewebappName didn't respond to HTTP pings on port: 9000, failing site start.**
```

getting :( Application Error while accessing sonarqube.

However same configuration works for sonarqube docker instance which is created locally and linked with same azure sql database.

Can you please help me out with this error.

```
az webapp config connection-string set --resource-group $RESOURCE_GROUP_NAME --name $WEBAPP_NAME -t SQLAzure --settings SONARQUBE_JDBC_URL=$DB_CONNECTION_STRING --connection-string-type SQLAzure

az webapp config container set --name $WEBAPP_NAME--resource-group $RESOURCE_GROUP_NAME --docker-custom-image-name $CONTAINER_REGISTRY_FQDN/$CONTAINER_IMAGE_NAME:$CONTAINER_IMAGE_TAG --docker-registry-server-url https://$CONTAINER_REGISTRY_FQDN --docker-registry-server-user $REG_ADMIN_USER --docker-registry-server-password $REG_ADMIN_PASSWORD
```

Comment: Investigate the SonarQube logs in the container.

Comment: In container logs of azure app service instance what i get as below logs
2019-06-13 14:29:28.296 INFO  - Waiting for response to warmup request for container SonarQubewebappName. Elapsed time = 49.4772459 sec
2019-06-13 14:29:44.637 INFO  - Waiting for response to warmup request for container SonarQubewebappName. Elapsed time = 65.8173845 sec
**2019-06-13 14:29:56.670 ERROR - Container SonarQubewebappName for site SonarQubewebappName has exited, failing site start
2019-06-13 14:29:56.693 ERROR - Container SonarQubewebappName didn't respond to HTTP pings on port: 9000, failing site start.**

Comment: I found the issue. Issue is with connection string what i am passing in **entrypoint.sh** as **SONAR_JDBC_URL.**
But Actually connection string should append below parameters 
**SQL Server: SQLCONNSTR_
MySQL: MYSQLCONNSTR_
SQL Database: SQLAZURECONNSTR_
Custom: CUSTOMCONNSTR_**
Please refer document for more clarity:
[hyperlink](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/configure-common#configure-connection-strings)